# check if same value exist in an input box

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, input

Is there anyway to check if a similar value  exist in an input box

```
EX:
<input name="user1" value="bla1">
<input name="user2" value="bla2">
<input name="user3" value="bla1">
```

The verification will trigger when the form is submitted, it will alert the user and add a class to both the input with the similar value.

Comment: And would that only be the default value, or a value added by a user, there's a difference as the attribute doesn't change when a user inputs a different value ?

Comment: @adeneo value added so it's not default

Comment: That's what I thought, otherwise it would be as simple as `$('[value=something]').length > 1` in a filter etc.

Comment: @adeneo yeah, I edited it.If it's just that simple I wouldn't need to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More jQuery'ish

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.filter(function(i,el){
    return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
        return this.value === el.value;
    }).length !== 0;
}).addClass('red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qjqa1et2/)

Filters the inputs based on wether or not another input with the same value exists

Comment: How do i check duplicate entries only for non-empty inputs?

Comment: added if( this.value != '') after inputs.filter(function(i,el){ , I hope it is the right way

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, by using a temporary object to keep track of elements of a particular value:

```js
(function() {
  var inputs = {};
  $('input').each(function() {
    if (inputs[this.value] !== undefined) {
      // a previous element with the same value exists
      // apply class to both elements
      $([this, inputs[this.value]]).addClass('same');
    }
    inputs[this.value] = this;
  });
}());
```

```css
.same {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="user1" value="bla1">
<input name="user2" value="bla2">
<input name="user3" value="bla1">
<input name="user4" value="bla4">
<input name="user5" value="bla5">
```

Comment: Upvote for actually having comments in the code that explain what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
var dup = false;
$.each("input", function(k, v){
  if($(this).attr("name") == $(this).next("input").attr("name")){
    dup = true;
  }
  if($this).is(":last")){
    if($(this).attr("name") == $("input:first").attr("name")){
      dup = true;
    }
  }
});
```